# multi-variable standard deviation with override for correlation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have a multi-variable framework where I have 3 variables with different weights and an array of variations such has :

```
import numpy as np
weights = np.array([-2.61540125, -0.2480875, -0.2737325])
var = np.array([[0.00660683, -0.03470032, -0.02153846],
                [0.00458204, -0.02614379, -0.02830189],
                [-0.00098619, -0.00671141,  0.0032362],
                [0.00175217, -0.02591793, -0.01217039],
                [0.00077738,  0.00886918,  0.00821355],
                [0.00077677, -0.02197802,  0.00100000]])
```

I can easily calculate the standard deviation with `np.dot`:

```
cov = np.cov(var.T)
standard_deviation = np.sqrt(weights.T.dot(cov).dot(weights))
standard_deviation

Out: 
0.0044526680008974574
```

but I would like to override the correlation matrix and assume a correlation of 1 for all variable and find a standard deviation based on that assumption. is there any simple matrix operation I can do with numpy to do this? I can do it with a loop but I feel like this is not efficient

the result should be :

```
0.015335270585229297
```

I did this to arrive to it:

```
def stdev(weights, corr, stdev):
    total = 0.0
    for i in range(0, len(weights)):
        for j in range(0, len(weights)):
            if i < j:
                total = total + weights[i] * stdev[i] * weights[j] * stdev[j] * corr[i, j]
            else:
                total = total + weights[i] * stdev[i] * weights[j] * stdev[j] * corr[j, i]
    return total ** 0.5

cor_one = np.ones(var.shape)
stdev = pd.DataFrame(var).std(ddof=1)
stdev(weights, cor_one, stdev)
```

Comment: Could you add how after computation ouput look like?

Comment: @Bharath it only returns a float, added output

Comment: I mean the output you want. To override correlation matrix in the sense to replace the values in `cov`?

Comment: @Bharath added answer, yes I would like to modify COV to reflect a correlation of 1 but the same variance for each variable

Comment: cant you just use `np.ones()` as cov?